# Extracting groupings contained within a single column in a python pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

There is an excel file which looks like the below image:

[image]

After using `pd.read_excel()` I have a dataframe that looks like so:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Accessory Description':['GROUP1','item1', 'item2','item3','item4','item5','GROUP2','item6','item7','item8'
                                   ,'item9','item10','GROUP3','item11','item12','item13','item14','item15']})
```

[image]

However I would like to manipulate the dataframe so that it is displayed as shown below:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Group':['Group1','Group1','Group1','Group1','Group1','Group2','Group2','Group2','Group2','Group2'
                   ,'Group3','Group3','Group3','Group3','Group3']
          ,'Accessory Description':['item1', 'item2','item3','item4','item5','item6','item7','item8'
                                   ,'item9','item10','item11','item12','item13','item14','item15']})
```

[image]

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.isupper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isupper.html)with [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and ffill for groups and then remove rows with same values in both columns:

```
s = df['Accessory Description'].where(df['Accessory Description'].str.isupper()).ffill()
df.insert(0, 'Group', s)

df = df[df['Group'].ne(df['Accessory Description'])].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
     Group Accessory Description
0   GROUP1                 item1
1   GROUP1                 item2
2   GROUP1                 item3
3   GROUP1                 item4
4   GROUP1                 item5
5   GROUP2                 item6
6   GROUP2                 item7
7   GROUP2                 item8
8   GROUP2                 item9
9   GROUP2                item10
10  GROUP3                item11
11  GROUP3                item12
12  GROUP3                item13
13  GROUP3                item14
14  GROUP3                item15
```